# Overloading == operator causes discards qualifiers error

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I am making a complex number class using C++. And I want to overload the == operator.
But I got this error:

```
In file included from Complex.cpp:1:0,
             from testComplex.cpp:2:
Complex.h: In function ‘bool operator==(const Complex&, const Complex&)’:
Complex.h:29:21: error: passing ‘const Complex’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘double Complex::real()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     return (c1.real() == c2.real() && c1.imag() == c2.imag());
```

Here is my class file:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H

class Complex{
    public:
    Complex(void);
    Complex(double a, double b);
    Complex(double a);
    double real(){ 
        return a;
    }

    double imag(){
        return b;
    }
    private:
    double a;
    double b;
};

bool operator==(const Complex& c1, const Complex& c2){
    return (c1.real() == c2.real() && c1.imag() == c2.imag());
}
#endif
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is basically saying that you seem to be using a function of a **read-only** object that is **allowed to alter** it. Imagine if you could call a member function say `IncrementImaginary();` on a **read-only** Complex object, you'd be **altering** a **read-only** object!

This is why when your member functions **do not alter** the variables (i.e. the **state**) of your class, you should attach a `const` qualifier to them like this:

```cpp
double real() const{
  return a;
}
```

This way, the compiler will know that it is safe to run this function on a **read-only** object of your class.

Comment: It works! Thank you. So whenever I define an accessor function, I need to put a const to indicate that it is read only?

Comment: As long as the member function does not alter the **state** of your class, where a typical example would be the **accessor function** you mentioned, it is generally good practice to mark the function as **read-only** so that users of your class will know what they can and cannot do with a **read-only** object of your class.